# play video on tft lcd screen connected to arduino uno from camera that also connected to the same arduino uno

Tags: video, arduino, live, playback

Is it possible to play live video on tft lcd screen connected to arduino uno from camera that also connected to the same arduino uno?
If this is not possible with arduino uno is it possible with another version of arduino?

Comment: an lcd monitor? or a bare screen with no controller, meaning you'd need the arduino be the controller?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible with any version of Arduino :). You better take a look on Raspberry Pi. Arduino can't do any digital encoding/transmission of video. It has about 2kb RAM. That's about 0.3% of *one* frame of 640*480 video.